# Mapping column names in Hive with JSON serde

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I'm using the built-in JSON serde in Hive to create an external table, i.e. `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`.  My input JSON contains a field called `last`, which I would like to map to a different column name in my table, since `last` is a reserved keyword.

Is this possible to do with `SERDEPROPERTIES`?  I can find examples of how to do this with the [OpenX Json serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde), but not the hive one.

Currently I'm creating my table like this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
    a string,
    b string,
    last string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last` is a **non-reserved** keyword.
No issue here.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords

```
hive> dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/*;
{"a":"hello","b":"world","last":"!"}
```

---

```
create external table my_table 
(
    a       string
   ,b       string
   ,last    string
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
    location '/user/hive/warehouse/my_table'
;
```

---

```
select * from my_table
;
```

---

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
| my_table.a | my_table.b | my_table.last |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| hello      | world      | !             |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

For **reserved** keywords, qualification with **`** (Grave accent) solves the issue.

```
hive> dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/my_table_2/*;
{"and":"X","or":"Mix","not":"Drix"}
```

---

```
create external table my_table_2
(
    `and`   string
   ,`or`    string
   ,`not`   string
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
    location '/user/hive/warehouse/my_table_2'
;
```

---

```
select * from my_table_2
;
```

---

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| my_table_2.and | my_table_2.or | my_table_2.not |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| X              | Mix           | Drix           |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I stand corrected - thank you for a comprehensive answer.  I'm in fact encountering a problem when using AWS Athena - `SELECT * FROM my_table` works but `SELECT last FROM my_table` doesn't.  Sounds like this problem may be specific to Athena.

Answer (score 0):

Use ' single quote for key word.  sample code

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
    a string,
    b string,
    'last' string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/data'
```

Comment: \`last\` string

Comment: Wrong symbol. Not `'` but `\``

Comment: Is last reserved?

Comment: it should be  (')  single quote how it is look .